# Approximating unitary matrices

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis, solovay-kitaev-algorithm

I currently have 2 unitary matrices that I want to approximate to a good precision with the fewer quantum gates possible.

In my case the two matrices are:

- The square root of NOT gate (up to a global phase)
  $$G = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} i & 1 \\ 1 & i \end{pmatrix} = e^{-\frac{3}{4}\pi} \sqrt{X}$$
- $$W = 
  \begin{pmatrix} 
  1&0&0&0\\
  0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0\\
  0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}&0\\
  0&0&0&1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$$

My question is the following:

> How can I approximate these specific matrices with the fewer quantum gates possible and a good precision?

What I want to have an can afford to have it:

1. I can afford to use several days/weeks of CPU time and a **lot** of RAM.
2. I can afford to spend 1 or 2 human days searching for mathematical tricks (in last resort, that is why I ask here first). This time does not include the time I would need to implement the hypothetical algorithms used for the first point.
3. I want the decomposition to be nearly exact. I don't have a target precision at the moment, but the 2 gates above are used extensively by my circuit and I don't want errors to accumulate too much.
4. I want the decomposition to use the fewest quantum gates possible. This point is secondary for the moment.
5. A good method would let me choose the trade-off I want between the number of quantum gates and the precision of the approximation. If this is not possible, an accuracy of at least $10^{-6}$ (in terms of trace norm) is probably (as said before, I do not have estimates so I am not sure of this threshold) required.
6. The gate set is:
   $$
   \left\{ H, X, Y, Z, R_\phi, S, T, R_x, R_y, R_z, \text{CX}, \text{SWAP}, \text{iSWAP}, \sqrt{\text{SWAP}} \right\}
   $$
   with $R_\phi, \text{SWAP}, \sqrt{\text{SWAP}}$ as described in [Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate), $R_A$ the rotation with respect to the axe $A$ ($A$ is either $X$, $Y$ or $Z$) and 
   $$\text{iSWAP} = \begin{pmatrix}   1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
     0 & 0 & i & 0  \\
     0 & i & 0 & 0  \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\ \end{pmatrix}$$.

The methods I know about:

1. The Solovay-Kitaev algorithm. I have an implementation of this algorithm and already tested it on several unitary matrices. The algorithm generates sequences that are quite long and the trade-off [number of quantum gates] VS [precision of the approximation] is not enough parametrisable. Nevertheless, I will execute the algorithm on these gates and edit this question with the results I obtained.
2. Two papers on [1-qubit gate approximation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6253) and [n-qubit gate approximation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0506). I also need to test these algorithms.

EDIT: edited the question to make "square root of not" more apparent.

Comment: Do you have any specific gate-set in mind and is there a reason you can't implement $G$ natively/directly on the qubit?

Comment: Edited to precise the gate-set I had in mind :)

Comment: Looks like W can be done with the right sqrt(SWAP) + one CNOT + single-qubit gates.

Comment: I'm curious about what you're trying to do with this, if you wouldn't mind elaborating.

Comment: These two gates are appearing in quantum circuits to simulate very simple Hamiltonians (1-sparse hamiltonians with only real entries or only imaginary entries). The thesis that elaborate on this is quite hard to obtain. The only way I found is to ask for a copy [here](https://prism.ucalgary.ca/handle/1880/41417) and wait for an answer on your mailbox :)

Comment: Have you tried BQSKit? It has state-of-the-art approximate synthesis algorithms and produces extremely good circuits. Check out their tutorial: https://github.com/BQSKit/bqskit-tutorial

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have picked two particularly simple matrices to implement.

The first operation (G) is just the square root of X gate (up to global phase):

[image: G gate]

In your gate set, this is $R_X(\pi/2)$.

The second operation (W) is a Hadamard matrix in the middle 2x2 block of an otherwise-identity matrix. Anytime you see this 2x2-in-the-middle pattern you should think "controlled operation conjugated by CNOTs". And that's exactly what works here (note: you may need to swap the lines; depends on your endianness convention):

[image: W operation]

So the only real trouble is how to implement a controlled Hadamard operation. A Hadamard is a 180 degree rotation around the X+Z axis. You can use a 45 degree rotation around the Y axis to move the X+Z axis to the X axis, then do a CNOT in place the CH, then move the axis back:

[image: W operation again]

Where $Y^{1/4} \equiv R_Y(\pi/4)$.

Answer (score 7):

When a two qubit gate $W$ can be expressed (up to a global phase) in the computational basis by a matrix with entirely real entries, i.e., $W \in O(4)$, then there is general construction of implementing the gate with $CNOTs$ and single qubit gates, please see [Vatan and Williams](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0308006v3).

The construction is optimal in the sense that it requires two CNOT gates and at most 12 single qubit gates (for the most general case of a real two qubit gate).
The construction is based on the homomorphism:

$$SO(4) \approx SU(2) \times SU(2),$$
which asserts that any two-qubit gate $W$ with real entries can be expressed as:
$$W = M U M^{\dagger}$$
with $U\in SU(2) \otimes SU(2)$ , i.e., can be implemented by two single qubit gates.

A matrix $M$ inducing this homomorphism is named by Makhlin the magic matrix, one possible solution is given on the bottom of page 2 in Vatan and Williams work, another possibility is given in equation (10) by [Fujii](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.1487v1).
Vatan and Williams gave a construction with one CNOT for $M$

[image]

Using this construction, the full gate implementation given by Vatan and Williams is:

[image]

with $S_1 = S_z(\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $R_1 = S_y(\frac{\pi}{2})$

Using this construction, it should be a quite an easy exercise to compute the one-qubit gates $A$ and $B$, for your case.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of these gates require approximate sequences. You can implement them exactly with your specified gate sets with no great effort.

Up to a global phase (which should be irrelevant), G is simply $HSH$.

The second, $W$, is a little more complicated. The way that I constructed this was to think of it as a controlled-Hadamard where I then required a basis change which is created by a controlled-not. One therefore has the circuit

[image]

where $U=\cos\frac{\pi}{8}\mathbb{I}-i\sin\frac{\pi}{8}Y$. I always get factors of 2 wrong in these angles, but this is of the form $R_Y(\theta)$. I've taken no particular effort to optimise this gate sequence, but this is probably fairly good.